# Android, 2.0.1 / API 6?

Tags: android

What happened to Android API 6? It's not mentioned on http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html and it's nowhere to be found in the SDK manager in available packages etc.

Do I need to worry about targeting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about targeting it.  Any devices out there should have been updated by OTA updates, effectively eliminating this API level.

Comment: this is correct. One of my apps has ~200K installs and the total number of installs on devices running 2.0.1 is 8.